# each, ajax, promises and setting html the proper way

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Inside a (dynamically generated) table I search for and find the column named "VATNumber" and iterate over all (non-header) cells of that column, using the value (vat number) as a parameter to an ajax call.

The table and button:

```
<table id="ResultData">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th><th>Amount</th><th>VATNumber</th><th>Country</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1</td><td>10000.00</td><td>DE123456789</td><td>BE</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2</td><td>20000.00</td><td>NL000123456B01</td><td>BE</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>3</td><td>30000.00</td><td>NL001234567B01</td><td>BE</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4</td><td>40000.00</td><td>NL002345678B01</td><td>BE</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>
    <button id="btnVIESCheck">CHECK</button>
</p>
```

This is more or less what the code looks like with (icky) synchronous ajax (contradiction in terms)

```
$('#btnVIESCheck').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var columnIndex = $('#ResultData th:contains("VATNumber")').index();
    $('#ResultData tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex + 1) + ')')
      .each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var vatnr = $this.text(),
            rowIndex = $this.closest('tr').index();

        //add ajaxloader
        $this.html($this.html() + '&nbsp;' + ajaxloader);

        var resultCode = checkVATNr(vatnr),
            img = '';

        switch (resultCode) {
            case '1':
                img = '<img src="Img/ok.jpg" />';
                break;
            case '2':
                img = '<img src="Img/notok.jpg" />';
                break;
            case '3':
                img = '<img src="Img/warning.jpg" />';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        $this.html(vatnr + ' ' + img);
    });
});

function checkVATNr(vatnr) {
    var result = '';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: 'MyWebService.asmx/CheckVATNumber',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'vatnr': vatnr
        }),
        success: function (msg) {
            var xml = $.parseXML(msg.d);
            $xml = $(xml);
            result = $xml.find('ResultCode').text();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error " + e.error);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Of course

- this shows the images when ALL the calls are done. Not preferable, the table might be very large
- I'd like to use proper async ajax inside the .each(), but then sometimes the results are garbled, out of order, replacing the wrong table cells and sometimes it only works for the last cell.

How can I write this using promises?

Comment: Some like this http://jsbin.com/wojecofogo/1/edit?js I'm not shure about data passing into done handler - but you can debut it ( or show your jsfiddle example )

Comment: that is because of the use of `async:false`

Comment: @VasilVanchuk again, this only shows an image for the last table cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is the use of global variable `$this` in the each loop, which will result in `$this` being always referring to the last `td` element. So use define it as a local variable like `var $this = $(this);`

That is because of the use of `async:false`, which blocks the browser thread from doing anything till all the ajax requests are finished.

Use callback mechanism to process the requests like

```
$('#btnVIESCheck').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var columnIndex = $('#ResultData th:contains("VATNumber")').index();
    $('#ResultData tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex + 1) + ')')
        .each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var vatnr = $this.text(),
            rowIndex = $this.closest('tr').index();

        //add ajaxloader
        $this.html($this.html() + '&nbsp;' + ajaxloader);

        checkVATNr(vatnr, function (resultCode) {
            var img = '';
            switch (resultCode) {
                case '1':
                    img = '<img src="Img/ok.jpg" />';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    img = '<img src="Img/notok.jpg" />';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    img = '<img src="Img/warning.jpg" />';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            $this.html(vatnr + ' ' + img);
        })

    });
});

function checkVATNr(vatnr, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'MyWebService.asmx/CheckVATNumber',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'vatnr': vatnr
        }),
        success: function (msg) {
            var xml = $.parseXML(msg.d);
            $xml = $(xml);
            callback($xml.find('ResultCode').text());
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Error " + e.error);
            callback('');
        }
    });
}
```

Also see: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: When I `console.log` each resultCode, they all come back as 1, yet only  the html for the last cell is set. Exactly what I encountered before. The others just keep showing the ajaxloader. Strange.

Comment: where did you add the `console.log()`?

Comment: right before the switch. I used `console.log('resultCode for vatnr ' + vatnr + ' is ' + resultCode);` and it does show the different vat numbers

Comment: @WimOmbelets missing `var` before `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: Oh dear... all of this over a missing var keyword -_-  I CANNOT believe this. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: You should edit your answer, I'll gladly upvote and accept it

Comment: @WimOmbelets already edited to add the `var`, but still you should not use `async:false`

Comment: I know, I started out using async, then out of despair, I tried using `async:false` because I -wrongly- assumed it was a promises issue. Thanks again for your time.